# Satisfiability and validity in first-order logic

Tags: logic, terminology, first-order-logic, satisfiability

There seems to be a subtle point about the concepts of satisfiability vs validity in first-order logic that I could use some clarification on.

These terms are usually defined as follows. A first order sentence is:

- **Valid** iff it is true in every model
- **Satisfiable** iff it is true in some model

But since FOL admits quantifiers, there seem to be some strange and counterintuitive quirks to this when free variables get involved. It seems to me that we have four possibilities. A formula with free variables can:

1. Hold for **all** objects in **all** models ("Valid?")
2. Hold for **some** objects in **all** models (??)
3. Hold for **all** objects in **some** models (??)
4. Hold for **some** objects in **some** models ("Satisfiable?")

In other words, we can consider the universal or existential closure of the formula, and then separately ask whether it holds in all or just some models.

What terminology do we use for these four cases?

Comment: By definition, a *sentence* has no free variables. Sentences that hold in all models are called valid and sentences that hold in some models are called satisfiable (that covers your 1 and 4 for sentences). For formulas with free variables, I don't believe there is any standard terminology. Why do you ask?

Comment: Thanks - changed to formula. I'm asking because the answer to this question confused me: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617263/validity-of-first-order-formulae-with-free-variables

Comment: The answer to that question is not very good: a sentence like $\forall x\forall y(x = y)$ is satisfiable but not "true" (or better "valid") because it holds in some models but not in all models. There is no general agreement about whether to take the universal closure or the existential closure in this connection (although the universal closure is the more common convention). But it doesn't make any difference if you start with a sentence - and then you have to address the possibility that a given sentence may be true in some models but not in others.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: thanks for pointing out a very significant typo.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful, I guess it's just a matter of convention then. If you want to write this up as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: 1. The formula is valid. 2. The existential closure of the formula is valid. 3. The universal closure of the formula is satisfiable. 4. The formula is satisfiable. (That's what I would say, but I'm not a logician.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** we define the *semantics* for formulas with free variables, like in [Enderton's textbook](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA83), we have that a formula $\varphi$ is *satisfied in* a structure $\mathfrak A$ *with* a *variable assignment* $s$, in symbols:

> $\mathfrak A,s \vDash \varphi$.

Thus, the formula $x=0$ is *satisfiable* because the structure $\mathbb N$ with the assignment $s(x)=0$ will do.

A formula $\varphi$ is *true in* a structure $\mathfrak A$ if it is satisfied with every variable assignment.

A formula is *valid* iff for every structure $\mathfrak A$ and every assignment $s$, $\mathfrak A$ satisfy $\varphi$ with $s$.